# IQueryable result different from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My task is to optimize some methods and while looking at code I found this bottleneck (I apologize if the formatting seems off):

```
// ...
    IEnumerable<Card> storageCards = 
        Db.StorageCards
          .Where(x => x.Active && x.DocumentType == (int)DocumentType.Import);

    // excludeLastDate is bool
    storageCards = storageCards.Where(x => (excludeLastDate && x.Date < toD) 
                                        || (!excludeLastDate && x.Date <= toD));

    return LocationPriceData(storageCards, locationId.Value);
}

private Dictionary<int, decimal> LocationPriceData(IEnumerable<Card> storageCards
                                                   , int locationId)
{
    // sc.LocationId, sc.ProductId are nullable int
    // sc.Price is nullable decimal
    // sc.Date is datetime, not null
    var result = from sc in storageCards
                    where sc.LocationId == locationId
                    group sc by sc.ProductId
                        into g
                        let price = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
                                     .ThenByDescending(t => t.Id)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Price.HasValue)
                        where price != null
                        select new
                        {
                            ProductId = g.Key.Value,
                            Price = price.LevelInputPrice.Value
                        };

    return result.ToDictionary(x => x.ProductId, x => x.Price);
}
```

To improve it I changed `storageCard` type form `IEnumerable<Card>` to `IQueryable<Card>` (in `LocationPriceData` signature as well) which made a huge difference, but now the results are different also!

I understand that the performance improvement happened due to the `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` implementation difference and that different data is fetched from database, but why is the end result different?

I'm suspecting the `group` part but as it is comparing a nullable int I can't see a reason for different result? Db is MS SQL server.

Oh, and in both cases the materialization happens at the `return result.ToDictionary(x => x.ProductId, x => x.Price);` line

**EDIT**

When changing to IQueryable the generated query is not like what I expected.
The Cross Apply does not have any ordering in it!

The logic behind following code is never executed on DB:

```
                    let price = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
                                 .ThenByDescending(t => t.Id)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Price.HasValue)
```

Here is the generated sql:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Element1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
[Element1].[LevelInputPrice] AS [LevelInputPrice]
FROM   (SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId]
        FROM [dbo].[StorageCard] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ((([Extent1].[Active] = 1) AND (10 = [Extent1].[DocumentType])) OR (40 = [Extent1].[DocumentType]) OR ((70 = [Extent1].[DocumentType]) AND ([Extent1].[InputQuantity] > cast(0 as decimal(18))))) AND (((@p__linq__0 = 1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] < @p__linq__1)) OR ((@p__linq__2 <> cast(1 as bit)) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__3))) AND ([Extent1].[LocationId] = @p__linq__4)
    )  AS [Distinct1] ) AS [Project2]
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent2].[DocumentType] AS [DocumentType], 
    [Extent2].[InputQuantity] AS [InputQuantity], 
    [Extent2].[LevelInputPrice] AS [LevelInputPrice], 
    [Extent2].[Active] AS [Active], 
    [Extent2].[LocationId] AS [LocationId], 
    [Extent2].[ProductId] AS [ProductId]
    FROM [dbo].[StorageCard] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ((([Extent2].[Active] = 1) AND (10 = [Extent2].[DocumentType])) OR (40 = [Extent2].[DocumentType]) OR ((70 = [Extent2].[DocumentType]) AND ([Extent2].[InputQuantity] > cast(0 as decimal(18))))) AND (((@p__linq__0 = 1) AND ([Extent2].[Date] < @p__linq__1)) OR ((@p__linq__2 <> cast(1 as bit)) AND ([Extent2].[Date] <= @p__linq__3))) AND ([Extent2].[LocationId] = @p__linq__4) AND (([Project2].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[ProductId]) OR (([Project2].[ProductId] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[ProductId] IS NULL))) AND ([Extent2].[LevelInputPrice] IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Element1]
WHERE [Element1].[Id] IS NOT NULL',N'@p__linq__0 bit,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 bit,@p__linq__3 datetime2(7),@p__linq__4 int',@p__linq__0=0,@p__linq__1='2017-07-19 08:43:52.6901840',@p__linq__2=0,@p__linq__3='2017-07-19 08:43:52.6901840',@p__linq__4=11
```

Comment: Looking at the profiler, a query is received at the `ToDictionary` line?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić ..Which.. appears to be what you were saying anyway; so disregard my comments :)

Comment: @Rob np, thank you for your input anyway. Made me read up on evaluation vs matrialization

Comment: @TadijaBagarić Are you able to show the SQL query that's being generated? You should be able to see it in the profiler. And in terms of the results being difference, are you sure all the data is different? Or perhaps it's just in a different order? If you can identify rows which are excluded in one query, that might give you some insight into what's happening, if you compare it to rows which are not excluded

Comment: @Rob you are right, there is a good possibility there is a bug here. I am looking in to it right now. Still not sure which of two versions gives the right output. Data order is ok, it is the Price numbers that are different. -- But, to help recognize and avoid future mistakes, I would appreciate some explanation to why these differences happen

Comment: @TadijaBagarić From a glance, there doesn't seem to be anything immediately obvious. The group should work fine (grouping by null in the DB and in memory should behave the same). The only explanation I can think of would be the ordering, if there are multiple rows with the same date and ID. Otherwise, I'd need to look at the actual row being operated on, and the result produced from both approaches for that row

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov the results are different which implies a bug and, unfortunately, broken code is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @TadijaBagarić you wants to optimize the code, your current optimization is not working for you. May be you need to ask how to optimize the code instead of asking how to fix current broken code?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I disagree; the fact that this bug came up during optimization doesn't mean it's a suitable question for code review. And even if it *were* suitable, that doesn't mean it should be migrated; it's perfectly on topic here.

Comment: This is probably a difference between Linq to Sql and Linq to Entities which are not guaranteed to produce the same results. For example string comparsions in Linq To Entities are case sensitive whereas in Linq to sql they may or may not be (depends on how the sql server is configured). Also filtering not equal to a value will exclude null values in Linq to Sql, but include them in Linq to Entities. Neither of these cases would appear to apply to your query, but there may be other differences between them.

Comment: Looking at the generated sql a bit closer, I does not look like it is generated by the linq statements you mention. It filters by InputQuantity which is not mentioned in your linq statements, the allows several values for DocumentType (but your Linq Statements only allow one) and the actual syntax of the generated TSQL do not look like standard Linq2Sql output (eg `Extent1 , Extent2 , @p__linq__0` etc where I would expect `t0, t1, @p0` etc).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with the query syntax in LINQ. I have a feeling that a `let` statement may not be supported by the ORM due to its complexity. It is strange, though, that it's completely omitted from the SQL, rather than generating an error.

Try giving this a shot, instead:

```
var result = storageCards
    .Where(sc => sc.LocationId == locationId)
    .GroupBy(sc => sc.ProductId)
    .Select(g => new {
        ProductId = g.Key.Value,
        Price = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)
                 .ThenByDescending(t => t.Id)
                 .Where(t => t.Price.HasValue)
                 .Select(t => t.LevelInputPrice.Value)
                 .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Where(a => a.Price != null);
```

Comment: I tried a similar let statement and Linq2Sql copes with it fine.

Comment: Tnx, not the answer I needed, but it got me to the answer.